# Add text to string using regular expression(preg_replace:php) with restricted words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds

I have a boolean search **string** for third party index search service: `Germany or (Indian, Tech*)`

I want my result to be after processing: `Germany[45] or (Indian[45], Tech*[45])`. Here 45 is the weight needed by the search service.

After googling around for long I was able to get the result: `Germany[45] or (Indian[45], Tech[45]*)`. Here you can see `*` has came after `[45]` which is not required.

The output should be: `Germany[45] or (Indian[45], Tech*[45])`, look for `*` before `[45]`.

Code:

`preg_replace('/([a-z0-9\*\.])+(\b(?<!or|and|not))/i', '$0'."[45]", $term);`

So the simple concept behind it is to apply weight to words, but not to `or/and/not` etc. boolean search sensitive words. Please help me to fine tune the regexp or give a new regex to get required result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that you were only getting matches that include a `\b` - a word boundary. Since an asterisk is a non-word character, it was eliminating it from the match, so the solution was to allow for either a word boundary or an asterisk `(\*|\b)`:

```
preg_replace('/([a-z0-9.]+)((\*|\b)(?<!or|and|not))/i', '$0'."[45]", $term);
```

However, it's simpler to do it with a negative lookahead:

```
preg_replace('/\b(?!or|and|not)([a-z0-9*.]+)/i', '$0'."[45]", $term);
```

Note: Within character classes asterisks and periods are not metacharacters, so they don't need to be escaped as you had in your original expression: `[a-z0-9\*\.]+`.

Comment: hey i got another case where this isn't working, plz update it."Soft Lang", its creating "Soft[45] Lang"[45], instead it  should respond as "Soft Lang"[45]. waiting for update

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookahead works like a charm:

```
preg_replace('/\b(?!or|and|not)([a-z0-9*.])+/i', '$0'."[45]", $term);
```

You can try it [HERE](http://regex101.com/r/kF6xW3)

Edit: Also no need to escape "*" and "." inside a character class

> Note that the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (), the caret (^) and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.
>
> Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/