# Find text within string and add additional text to it

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database, I have a field formatted as TEXT.
  Within some of these columns, it will contain

> src="/images/imgname.jpg"

As I pull the data from the database, how can I find this text and add additional text in front of "/images"?

> src="**http://domain.com**/images/imgname.jpg"

I don't want to make it permanent in the database as different files have different needs.  Some don't need the absolute path, while others do.  I just want to add them on the fly from some files.

Thanks!
Rick

Comment: Search in this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231256/add-text-to-string-using-regular-expressionpreg-replacephp-with-restricted-wo

Answer (score 1):

You could put it inside a while-loop with mysql_fetch_array().

```
$query = "SELECT query to select the wanted details from the database table.";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = $mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<img src='/domain.com/images/".$row['image_location']."'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple str_replace() should do the trick:

```
$value = 'src="/images/imgname.jpg"'; // Or whatever you fetched from the database
$value = str_replace('src="/images', 'src="http://domain.com/images', $value);
```

This way all occurences will be delt with, even if it's part of a larger text block. Using a regex for this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use regex with `preg_replace` if you want to replace all the images in the code.

Here is an example:

```
$code =
    '<img src="/images/imgname.jpg" />'.
    '<img src="/images/anotherimage.png" />';

$pattern = '/src="\/images\/(\w+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)"/i';
$replacement = 'src="http://domain.com/images/$1.$2"';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $code);
```

The result is:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/images/imgname.jpg" />
<img src="http://domain.com/images/anotherimage.png" />
```